# Project-wide Javascript/TypeScript language error from built-in language extension

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am getting the following error in VSCode whenever I open my workspace.

```
To enable project-wide JavaScript/TypeScript language features, exclude large folders with source files that you do not work on. 
Source: TypeScript and Javascript Language Feat... [BUTTON: CONFIGURE EXCLUDES]
```

I click the `Configure Excludes` button on the message and it opens the following file
`FRONTENDAPP/jsconfig.json`

```
{"compilerOptions":{"target":"es6","experimentalDecorators":true},"exclude":["node_modules","bower_components","tmp","vendor",".git","dist"]}
```

It looks to me that is configured correctly according to the documentation below. : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript

So why the error all the time?

My Workspace is setup as follows:

```
FOLDER: NOTES
FOLDER: FRONTENDAPP
FOLDER: BACKENDAPP
```

Each folder as a `jsconfig.json` file.

The respective file in the NOTES and BACKENDAPP is the same and looks as follows:

```
{"compilerOptions":{"target":"es6","experimentalDecorators":true},"exclude":["node_modules","bower_components","tmp","vendor",".git","dist"]}
```

Comment: Sounds like there are still large folders within each of your app folders.

Comment: How many JS/TS files are in your workspace?

Comment: Checking file counts gave me the right strategy. @MattBierner. I found a folder with quite a few js files and have excluded it now.

Answer (score 29):

Identify folders with lots of files:
`du -a | cut -d/ -f2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr`

```
162114 node_modules
5837 .git
4967 concat-stats-for
 443 app
  77 tests
  72 dist
   8 config
   7 public
```

Check folders that aren't excluded in `jsconfig.json` for JS and TS files

```
find concat-stats-for -type f | sed -e 's/.*\.//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | grep -Ei '(js|ts)$'

  42 ts
3003 js
```

If the folder isn't App code, add said folder to `jsconfig.json` exclude.

Answer (score 28):

I had the same issues and I realized:

1. I had `node_modules` in subfolders
2. I had copies of `dist` (like `dist1`, `dist2`) for debugging, which where gitignored but not vscode ignored.
3. I had `.npm` and `.npm-tmp` folders with a lot of stuff inside.
4. Apart from `dist` I also had another tmp folder `.app-cache`.

I ended up with the following entry in `/jsconfig.json` (slightly redundant for readability) to make the warning go away:

```
  "exclude": [
    ".git",
    ".app-cache",
    ".npm",
    ".npm-tmp",
    "dist",
    "dist*",
    "node_modules",
    "subfolder/dist",
    "subfolder/node_modules",
    "**/dist/*",
    "**/node_modules/*",
  ]
}
```

Comment: For me it was my build folders - I specifically had storybook-static. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

For me what helped was to simply remove my `jsconfig.json`. The file only contained the following:

```json
{
    "typeAcquisition": {
        "include": [
            "jest"
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm thinking the contents of my `jsconfig.json` didn't have anything to do with it, but the mere existence of a `jsconfig.json` file will probably override some built in fallbacks (based on `.gitignore` or similar?)

Answer (score 0):

for an example to exclude `src/posts` from tsserver indexing

add exclude in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "exclude": [
    "**/node_modules/**",
    "./page/**/*",
    "**/dist/**",
    "**/assets/js/core.js",
    "**/assets/js/v*.js",
    "**/assets/js/gijgo*.js",
    "**/packages/**",
    "**/src/posts/**",
    "**/src-posts/**",
    "**/source/_posts/**"
  ]
}
```

add these settings to `.vscode/settings.json`

```
{
  "files.exclude": {
    "src/posts": true
  },
  "files.watcherExclude": {
    "src/posts": true
  },
  "search.exclude": {
    "src/posts": true
  },
  "typescript.check.npmIsInstalled": false,
  "typescript.format.enable": false,
  "typescript.preferences.autoImportFileExcludePatterns": ["**/src/posts/**", "**/src-posts/**", "**/source/_posts/**"]
}
```

reload VSCode. done. warning gone.